# How can I create a multisite global tag cloud?

Tags: multisite, tags

I have a WordPress multisite installation.
I need to create a sitewide tagcloud on the main blog.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this plugin
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-sitewide-tags/
and this tutorial
http://wpmututorials.com/how-to/make-a-tags-page-like-wordpress-dot-com/

It says wpmu, but it is exactly the same.

Comment: needed a tag cloud on the sidebar, but it worked like a charm :-)

Comment: A better and more efficient way to do this would be to get all the tags from the database tables (like once a day or something like that, then cache results because the query would be very expensive).

Comment: .. which is what this plugin does... it aggregates everything to one blog, instead of looping through each.